# Decide typing depends on other key's value in interface (TypeScript)

Tags: typescript

```
interface InputProps {
  type: 'input' | 'textarea'
  props: | React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>
         | React.TextareaHTMLAttributes<HTMLTextAreaElement>
}
```

if `type: 'input'`, I want to limit `props` to be `React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>` type.

Comment: separate it out into an `input` and a `textarea` interface first, then  union on those.

Comment: If you can, please give me an example!

Answer (score 1):

you should define it as 2 separate interfaces, then combine them:

```
interface InputProps {
  type: 'input'
  props: React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>
}

interface TextAreaProps {
  type: 'textarea'
  props: React.TextareaHTMLAttributes<HTMLTextAreaElement>
}

type TextFieldProps = InputProps | TextAreaProps;
```